# How to measure the individual transaction response times for multiple file types with different file sizes upload operation

Tags: filesize, loadrunner

I have a requirement:  where I need to upload multiple file types (PDF, CSV, EXCEL, Word) with different file size(5MB, 25MB, 50MB, 500MB, 1GB) and measure the transaction response time for each of the file type and size upload operation (i.e. Combinations of file type and file size).
We have 10 active user for the Load Test Execution
E.g.:
PDF - 5MB - What is the file upload time?
EXCEL - 5MB - What is the file upload time?
CSV - 5MB - What is the file upload time?
Word - 5MB -  What is the file upload time?

PDF - 25MB - What is the file upload time?
EXCEL - 25MB - What is the file upload time?
CSV - 25MB - What is the file upload time?
Word - 25MB -  What is the file upload time?

PDF - 50MB - What is the file upload time?
EXCEL - 50MB - What is the file upload time?
CSV - 50MB - What is the file upload time?
Word - 50MB -  What is the file upload time?

Please let me know how can we prepare a LR scenario for this requirement

Answer (score 0):

Turn on time-taken in your web logs.   Run your test.  Pull the times from the web logs.

OR

Leverage the timing model covered in your LoadRunner training class to measure it at the front end.

Note: You can also pull the times from the logs during your unit, component assembly, manual, automated, & User acceptance testing

Comment: can you pls mention detailed steps to enable "Turn on time-taken in web logs" and how to pull the times from the web logs to fetch them dynamically during the load test execution in the controller.

Comment: You change your log model on your web server.  See documentation for adjusting the HTTP request logs entries for your web server (apache, nginx, iis, ....)   At the conclusion of the test use a log management tool to extract fields for date, time, request name.  See the LoadRunner analysis documentation for importing data from third party data sets and the CSV file format required.